# How do I list all channels that a particular user created in Slack?

Tags: slack

Is there a way to list all the channels created by a given user (or by Me)?
A search query like:

```
#channels created_by:@user.name
```

I dont see this information on user's profile page on Slack desktop client or Web.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via the API. Sample code in python:

```
client = WebClient(...)
response = client.conversations_list()
channels_i_created = [x for x in response.data['channels']
                      if x['creator'] == my_user_id]
```

Your user id can be obtained via `client.users_list` given a username. See https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list and https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list for more.